# Find the mean of the Geometric distribution from the MGF

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to show, using the MGF of $X$~$Geom(p)$, that he mean of this
distribution is $\frac{q}{p}$ and that the variance is $\frac{q}{p^2}$.

I know that the MGF of X is $M_x(t)=\frac{p}{1-qe^t}$ for $qe^t<1$. I also know that in order to show what I want to show, I need to take the first and second derivatives of $M_x(t)$ and show that they equal $\frac{q}{p}$ and $\frac{q}{p^2}$, respectively.

However, I am having trouble with my differentiation as below:

$$M_x^1(t)=(\frac{p}{1-qe^t})^1=\frac{(1-qe^t)-p(-tqe^{t-1})}{(1-qe^t)^2}=\frac{1-qe^t+tpqe^{t-1}}{(1-qe^t)^2}$$

And this is where I get stuck. I also tried to rewrite the MGF in the following way.

$$M_x^1(t)=(p(1-qe^t)^{-1})^1$$

But did not get much closer. I know this is a simple calculus mistake but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$M'_X(t)$ = $(1-qe^t) \frac{dp}{dt} - p \frac{d}{dt} (1-qe^t) \over {(1-qe^t)^2}$ = $0 + p qe^t \over {(1-qe^t)^2} $

$E[X] = M'_X(0) = \frac{q}{p}$

Can you do for variance now?